# Sum of 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 +.... + 1/n without iterations using digamma function and Euler's constant

Tags: c++, function, boost, cumulative-sum

So i like to make my life hard, i've got a task to calculate the sum of
`1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 +.... + 1/n`.
The conditions is to not use iterations but a closed formula. On this post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367037/sum-of-1-1-2-1-3-1-n

I've found a pretty neat looking solution: `1+1/2+1/3+⋯+1/n=γ+ψ(n+1)`
where  γ is Euler's constant and ψ is the digamma function.

For digamma I'm using the [boost c++ libraries](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_gamma/digamma.html) and I calculate the Euler's constant using exp(1.0).

The problem is that I don't get the right answer. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/digamma.hpp>


int main(){
int x; 
const double g = std::exp(1.0);

std::cin >> x;

std::cout<<g + boost::math::digamma(x+1);

return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance) !

Comment: You should state what result you expect and how it differs from what you get.

Comment: For example if n (or x in my code ) is 3 i should get 1.833 but my program gives 3.9744

Comment: This is still a math question. You want [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant), which is **not** `std::exp(1.0)` (Euler's *number*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Euler is known for having a lot of things named for him.

That can easily become confusing, as seems to be case here.

What you are adding to the digamma function result is *Euler's number*. You are supposed to add *Euler's constant*, which is a *different* number named after Euler.

You can find the correct number in boost as `boost::math::constants::euler`, e.g.:

```
const double g = boost::math::constants::euler<double>();
```

(Thanks @Eljay)

---

For some context on such how much is named after Leonhard Euler and how confusing it can get, here is the Wikipedia page's section on just *numbers* named after him, counting 11 different items: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Leonhard_Euler#Numbers

Comment: `const double g = boost::math::constants::euler<double>();`

Comment: Thanks now it works, I really didn't pay too much attention to that , thanks ))!